# IMPORTHTML Limits and Alternates

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to build a daily tracker for my work group and have been pulling the data from a weburl using IMPORTHTML function. But often the function fails saying Resource at url contents exceeded maximum size. What is the limit on the rows that can be imported using IMPORTHTML? It seems to be breaking somewhere around 10k rows.

If I have to import more rows than that, say 100k, what is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use apps script to accomplish it.

With [UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app) you can get all the data from your url.

Once you have the data you can use [SpreadsheetApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app) to insert these data in the sheet.